# Create custom archive page for individual authors which is separate from the author.php page

Tags: pages, archives, author

If this is a duplicate, I apologize. I have searched and searched with no luck.

I have a custom author.php set which shows the most recent 10 posts (As it's set in the admin panel under General > Reading). I want to have a link to "View all posts by this author". This will link to a page showing all posts by that specific author. All the information I've found has been about the author.php page which I don't want to change. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress template hierarchy accommodates this out of the box. WP will only use author.php if it cannot find author-{nicename}.php or author-{id}.php.

See the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Author_display).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to create another author page or even specific author pages per author. I guess I need to create a custom archive page that just shows posts from a specific author.